# What's the best way to slow (or stop) spam or bot activity on my .js form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is an example of an if statement on (.click)...

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
***********************************
var email = $('input[name=email]');  
***********************************
if (email.val()=='') {
    email.addClass('hightlight');
    return false;
    } else email.removeClass('hightlight');
...
$('#submit').click(function () {
...
var email = $('input[name=email]');
```

This is a PHP Ajax contact form with other data. I end up getting a lot of spam from for instance .ru (Russia), so would it be good to error out the most common ones in an if statement, or is it better to just go with a captcha. If so, any good references on a simple one visibly and use wise for this situation. The form is at 
http://www.shaneofalltrades.com/index.html#contact
Open to any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the best way is to use a captcha service like recaptcha. Or to just implement a simple random calculation that must be answered before the post. Somthing like "What is 1+3?"

Comment: I am going to think on this one, maybe something fun and simple with the addition idea.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing would be server-side validation (some kind of captcha). Do not rely on client side validations only.

Comment: indeed; javascript can just be turned off... it is only intended to make your site more responsive or more interactive, add effects etc.

Comment: I am using ajax/PHP while in .js process, maybe I can imbed the captcha there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by .js process, but CAPTCHA image is displayed in the browser, but is generated and validated on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet if you are getting a lot of spam would be just to add a captcha ([reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)).

You could add some code to only add the captcha if the comment includes a URL or something suspicious if you wanted.

Comment: As in an if ... %url% or whatever syntax looks for specific text then goes into reCaptcha if yes? I like this idea.

Answer (score 1):

> ...or is it better to just go with a captcha. If so, any good references on a simple one visibly and use wise for this situation...

[reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is very simple to integrate, widely-used, and well-supported.

Comment: This will be my last resort. The security for reCaptcha sounds great, but I want to try to get the least entries for my customers so I don't loose their interest. At least try things out first as my site reaches limited customers and low security needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) trigger on the form that sets a hidden variable to accept the form

```
<input type='hidden' name='isValid' value='no' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('form').mousemove(function(){
    $('input[name=isValid]').val('yes');
})
</script>
```

and check that on the server side.

Comment: nice I like this one, I will try this first before going into a new input option.

Comment: @Shane: Only do this if you're okay with shutting out people using accessibility software, as well as mobile/smartphone/touch-tablet users.

Comment: I see, I want to eventually make my site more mobile friendly (those are future questions) so maybe this is not the right choice? Maybe a "whats 1 + 1?" is a better temp plan until I can break down what jishi has mentioned.

Comment: binding that with input focus could to the trick with new smartphones and touch tablets, i also agree with Crowder , it's not so good, a 1+1 question, but with "1" being an image(bots tend to learn math) could do the trick nicely

Answer (score 1):

I have had good experience with either one of these two options:

1. Use a session-based token, that is generated on the page with the form, and then submitted with the form and then evaluated server side. This requires the "bot" to utilize cookies, and use two request in order to post your form. Most simple bots don't do this.
2. Use an onsubmit event hook that sets the actual form action upon submission. That way, a script can't easily read out the target url for posting, without having to process javascript. Example:

`<form onsubmit="this.action = ['formpost','php'].join('.')">`

You can obfuscate it even more by attaching the event in a separate js-file, however there will be no fallback for people with javascript disabled, removed or when the javascript on the page breaks.

ADDITION: There is a new service called keypic.com that is also worth looking into. http://www.keypic.com/

It works in the way that it relies on the client to actually fetch an image from a 3rd party server (most bots wouldn't) which you then can revalidate upon submission. This system is pretty easy to replicate yourself if you like.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer, I am going to get some sleep and go over the details in the morning.

Comment: This does, of course, require JavaScript. But I think Shane's page may already require it, so...

Comment: The first option doesn't require javascript, the second one does as I stated.

Comment: I understand the idea, but really need to study this before implementing into my files so I know whats really happening. Finish a final this evening then I will dive into it. One more question, what are the drawbacks to this code and/or what good customers could I effect? thanks again!

Comment: First option hasn't any real drawbacks, you only rely on session cookies for it to work. However, a smart bot can easily replicate the behavior if the want to. Second option relies on javascript, but "obfuscates" the actual target of the form. If you post it using XHR this might not help you at all because you could easily just set the post-target in your js, but if you have an action="" on your form, that is what the bot picks up. Captcha is pretty solid, but also pretty intrusive on the client and prone to irritation.

Comment: Added info about keypic as well.